# Bootstrap footer - Links - Social Media Logos - Links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm working on a footer for my website. I added social media logos from font-awesome and put it in the middle of my footer. When I added the links, the logos weren't in the middle anymore and you cannot see the links on the right side. I'm relatively new to HTML/CSS and I don't know how to fix it. What should I change that it looks like in the 2nd picture?
And how can I change the "px" in the CSS file into "%" that it looks same on every monitor?

Sorry if my English isn't the best, Thanks in advance. :)

What it looks like
[image: What it looks like]

What it should look like
[image: What it should look like]

My code:

```css
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #999999;
}
footer ul.footerleft{
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
footer ul.footerleft li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
footer a{
    color: #222;
}

footer a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;    
}
.social:hover {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 }
 .social {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
     color: #222;
     
 }
```

```html
<!-- footer -->
    <footer class="footer">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <ul class="footerleft">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 1</a>                   
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 2</a>                    
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center center-block">
                    <a href=""><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i id="social-gp" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i id="social-em" class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Link 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Text
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            </div>
            
        </nav>
    </footer>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/ with all the code and resources would be more helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by moving the navbar-right div to the top.

```
<footer class="footer">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <ul class="footerright">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Link 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Text
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <ul class="footerleft">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <a href=""><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i id="social-gp" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i id="social-em" class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
</footer>
```

Then added some css for the footerright:

```
footer ul.footerright{
        margin-right: 150px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    footer ul.footerright li{
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }
```